# Jenkins doesn't trigger a TFS change

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I've recently installed TFS plugins version 2.5.1 on Jenkins v.2.22.

I successfully configured `Team Project Collection URL` (Test connection works) and `Project Path`.

I also marked this build trigger:

```
"Build when a change is pushed to TFS/Team Services"
```

For some reason after I check-in some changes under the mentioned Project Path - nothing happens.

`Build now` option works fine.

`TFS/Team Services hook log` mentions that `Polling has not run yet.`

Can someone explain how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Which version are you using 2.5.1? The latest should be 5.2.1- [Jenkins Team Foundation Server Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin)... Typing error?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Answer (score 1):

First, please update your TFS plugin version to latest. Also check Team Foundation Server polling log to see if there's some related info.

If you are going to trigger Jenkins with VSTS, there's also some configuration in VSTS:

1. **Enable alternate credentials** in your Visual Studio Team Services
   profile. Be sure to set a secondary user name because you won't be
   able to use your email account to connect Visual Studio Team
   Services to Jenkins.
2. Go to your team project's administration page. On the Service Hooks
   tab, **create a subscription**. Add Jenkins.
3. Pick the event from Visual Studio Team Services that you want to
   trigger a Jenkins build.
4. Configure the action to take in Jenkins. Now, when that event occurs
   in Visual Studio Team Services, your Jenkins build will be
   triggered.

More details please check this tutorial: [Trigger Jenkins from Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/service-hooks/services/jenkins#trigger-jenkins-from-visual-studio-team-services)

Comment: Above steps are correct,But lets imagine my Jenkins server is running as a local host server.Its not open to outside / public, In this case how am i going to perform the 2nd step of your answer.